# multiple sites in apache2 aren't working

Tags: networking, server, apache2

Hello everyone I need help, I am trying  to create two local sites in my docker container with Ubuntu bom.com and bom2.com with article << https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-ubuntu-18-04/ >>.
I did all steps, created two folders in "/var/www/bom.com/index.html" and "/var/www/bom2.com/index.html", create conf files in "/etc/apache2/sites-available",
bom.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/bom.com"
    ServerName bom.com
    ServerAlias www.bom.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

, bom2.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/bom2.com"
    ServerName bom2.com
    ServerAlias www.bom2.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then disables default host with a2dissite 000-default.conf
Then enable two  sites with command:
a2ensite bom.com.conf
a2ensite bom2.com.conf
and set them in hosts

Reload apache2 with "service apache2 reload"
And tried to go to site "http://bom.com" but its goes to another site on interner, with "http://bm2.com" the same, I don't understand what is the problem, I am trying to resolve this for a week(

Comment: Please write me if you need more details)

Comment: Do you own the domain names?

Comment: bom.com and bom2.com do not point at the same IP address,  I guess that you don't own the domain names.  The domain names which you use for the virtual sites must point at your apache webserver.

Comment: Organic Marble: No, but if I want   sites wok local,  dont't I need just create conf file with server name?

Comment: SEWTGIYWTKHNTDS: Yes they are point to one IP address in file /etc/hosts,

Comment: SEWTGIYWTKHNTDS: I need own domain name even if It locally? 'The domain names which you use for the virtual sites must point at your apache webserver"- Can you please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: You will have to ensure (via a local configuration) that the server and your client computers all resolve the names to the. local  IP address of your apache server.  you could try using /etc/hosts or a local dns server.  I recommend changing the names to something you can control on your local network in either case

Comment: Try nslookup on the www.bom.com and www.bom2.com, you need them to return the IP address of your apache server.  The server name in the virtual server  should match the virtual site name so that when it responds to requests the url is correct.

Comment: I tried nslookup bom.com : << Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.bom.com     canonical name = me1w1qux3krj.wpeproxy.com.
Name:   me1w1qux3krj.wpeproxy.com
Address: 141.193.213.20
Name:   me1w1qux3krj.wpeproxy.com
Address: 141.193.213.21 >>
My IP is 172.17.0.1,  What should I do to fix this)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and the comments on the question, you will want to update your `/etc/hosts` file to have `bom.com` and `bom2.com` point to your local Apache installation. This is typically considered “bad practice” for development purposes, as using a `.com` does not give you a quick visual reference to confirm if you’re working locally or seeing a production site. That said, here’s how you can accomplish your goal:

0. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
1. Edit `/etc/hosts` with a text editor of your choice:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/hosts
   ```
2. Add records that point to your Docker container. For example:

   ```
   172.17.0.2    bom.com
   172.17.0.2    bom2.com
   ```
3. Save the file
4. Ensure “Developer Tools” is active on your browsers and have “Disable Cache” active. This will reduce the odds of the browser bypassing local name resolution to query the live sites.

**Note:** Other machines on your local network will not be able to connect to the Docker instance unless you also update the `hosts` file on each of those machines, or configure a local DNS server to point the network traffic accordingly.

Comment: I set hosts like <<172.17.0.2    bom.com>>
<<172.17.0.2    bom2.com>> , it is not working and after I restart my comp all my changes in file hosts disappeared

Comment: If the changes “disappeared”, then it’s unlikely you followed the steps above. No version of Linux replaces `/etc/hosts`, because there is no need to. The file is meant to be persistent over time.